# Have there been any fatal accidents involving a transatlantic flight since AF447?

Tags: accidents, accident-investigation, accident-statistics

I'm trying to confirm there has been no commercial airline transatlantic flight accident (with fatalities) since AF447 in 2009. This would include any flight that crossed the Atlantic ocean, even if the incident was on landing. I believe this is the case as of November 2021, but would like to be sure.

Comment: What are we trying to answer here? Dropping into the ocean (ala AF447) or something which has made a transatlantic flight and crashed on landing?

Comment: Are you looking for just airline flights? There are lots of transatlantic flights that are not airlines, such as military, research (NOAA, etc.), and even ferry flights of small, single-engine planes.

Comment: Does "transatlantic" mean anything that transits over the Atlantic ocean, or does it have to go to/from Europe/Asia/Africa to the Americas?

Comment: @FredLarson I did actually specify commercial, but Pondlife completely rephrased the question and removed important info

Comment: @Cloud I'm not sure which edit you mean. I changed the title only; another user changed the question body. In any case, it's your question and if edits aren't helpful then you should absolutely roll back or edit again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this counts (the planned route of flight included an Atlantic transit)...

[Fly Jamaica Airways 256 in 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly_Jamaica_Airways_Flight_256)

The aircraft was scheduled to fly from Guyana to Canada but experienced a hydraulic failure on the climb out, returned to the airport and overran the runway hitting a perimeter fence on landing.

Six people were injured and an 86 year old woman died of injuries 7 days later, so it is classified as a fatal accident.

Comment: I'm not sure [such route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNu5R.png) fully qualifies for transatlantic (which I associate to crossing the ocean) but you asked for details and were not answered, so it's fair. And it's indeed a very good find. +1